# How to make 3D histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, histogram

This is my goal: Plot the frequency of `y` according to `x` in the `z` axis.

These are my problems: I have a two columns array (`x` and `y`) and need to divide `x` into classes (p.ex. 0.2 ou 0.5) and calculate the frequency of `y` for each class of `x`. The plot should appear like a `x-y` plot in the "ground" plan and the frequency in the `z` axis. It could be like a surface or a 3D histogram. I tried to make it using the `hist3D` function of `plot3D` package but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is an example of what I am trying to do:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/r-data-visualization/9781783989508/ch06s05.html

Thanks!!

Comment: The colours in that example are reflected in the height and are redundant. You could do a 2d + colour heatmap and give the same information, without obscuring a chunk of the data behind high bars.

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks for the tip. I'll try the heatmap.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using some simulated data, this should get you what you want.  The key is that you have to create your bivariate bins, accomplished using the `cut()` function. Then treating the binned factors as levels we can then count the combinations of each factor level using the `table()` function like below:

```
library(plot3D)

##  Simulate data:
set.seed(2002)
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)

##  Create cuts:
x_c <- cut(x, 20)
y_c <- cut(y, 20)

##  Calculate joint counts at cut levels:
z <- table(x_c, y_c)

##  Plot as a 3D histogram:
hist3D(z=z, border="black")

##  Plot as a 2D heatmap:
image2D(z=z, border="black")
```

[image: 3D][image: 2D]

Comment: Thanks, man. I used your code in may data and it works pretty well, but as @thelatemail said, maybe a heatmap is the best option.

Comment: In this case I would certainly agree. :)  I edited my answer to document that as an option:

Comment: @Forrens R. Stevens, this way looks much better! Analyzing the new plots I'm thinking about something a little bit different, maybe you can help me with this too:
I want to make another plot using "independent histograms" for each `x` class plotted all together. Just to make it clear: the somatory of each column in your exemple should be 1. In this case, there will not be super high values in the scale, but a more smooth heatmap varying from 0 to 1.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. What do you mean by "somatory?" I assume you want the values scaled in some way, but by the maximum of the joint counts across all tables or by column?  And what do you mean by "smooth" heatmap?  You can vary your bin width to create more finely graded histograms if that's what you'd like?  Or you could take the resulting 2D heat map and interpolate it as well?

Comment: Sorry about my bad english. What I want is to scale the values by the `x` classes, using density (each `x` class must have an area of 1) instead of frequency, the absolute values of all plot. The central values of the heatmap are very high, obscuring the small variability on the edges. I just want to calculate de density of each `x` classes independently and then plot all together in a heatmap.

Comment: I'm still confused a touch about whether you want columns to be standardized so that the max value is 1 or whether you want each column to sum to one.  For the former you can use the following: `apply(z, 1, function(x) {x/apply(z, 2, max)})`

Comment: I've made this code to solve my problem. I know it's a dummy code, but it works fine. Looks the same of what you made if change `max` to `sum`, but without the `apply` function.
    
`for (j in 1:ncol(z)){
       for (i in 1:nrow(z)){
          new.z[i,j]<-z[i,j]/sum(z[,j])
    }}`

Comment: Indeed, that does exactly the same thing as the nested `apply()` functions.  Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: do you know if theres a way to make a heatmap with continuous scale instead of a discrete scale? Maybe using interpolation or something like this...

Comment: I'm a touch confused, the scale you see in the figures above is "continuous" in the sense that the floating point numbers (or integer counts in this case) are converted to RGB colors on the quantized/RGB scale you see on the right?

Comment: What I'm saying is if there`s a way to interpolate the matrix that I'm using to make the heat map. As you said, the scale is continuous (sorry, I wrote wrong), but I'd like to make the heatmap continuos, maybe applying some polinomial for each column that describes the 'y' values. I don't know if it's possible. As you can see I am quite new in R language

Comment: You can. One simple way is to convert your matrix object to a raster and interpolate it to a finer grid.  See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536951/interpolating-gridded-3d-data-to-a-finer-scale/30537990#30537990) for a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, Forrest! Thats exactly what I was looking for!