# Is there a way in R, that I can plot home and away score data of a basketball game, along with density in a 3D plot?

Tags: r, 3d

The plot should look like this. I am not sure how can I help. Any thoughts?
[image: a 3D plot]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to get a graph that *looks* like this 3-dimensional histogram.

Here is one (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563340/how-to-make-3d-histogram-in-r):

```
library(plot3D) # Load library

data("Hoops", package = "Stat2Data") # Load example data 

x <- Hoops$OppPoint
y <- Hoops$GrPoint
x_c <- cut(x, 15) # Format the x-axis data
y_c <- cut(y, 15) # Format the y-axis data
z <- table(x_c, y_c) # Create z-axis data

##  Plot as a 3D histogram with hist3D
hist3D(z = z, border = "black")
```

And the result:

[image: 3D histogram]

Since I usually prefer 2-dimensional graphs to visualize this kind of data, here is an alternative using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2) # Load ggplot2

ggplot(Hoops, aes(OppPoint, GrPoint)) + 
  geom_hex(binwidth = c(10, 10), color = "white", size = 1) +  # Use hexbin geometry
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") + # Change palette (personnal pref.)
  coord_equal() + 
  theme_bw() # Change theme (personnal pref.)
```

And the result

[image: 2D hexbin plot]

NB1: for these chunks of code to work, you will need to [install the packages](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/installing-and-using-r-packages) `plot3D` (for the 3D histogram), `Stat2Data` (for the `Hoops` data), and `ggplot2` (for the 2D hexbin plot).

NB2: before you will get to the point where you can play around with your graph, you will need to format your data in a way that the plotting function will understand it. That's usually a little bit tricky.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response . Now I would like to ask some queries . 1) Is there an efficient way to select how to cut the data points ? , 2) can I move the graph in order to have a look on the x=y line ?

Comment: Sure, would you like to edit your question to include an example data-set and show us where you are stuck?

Comment: In the meantime, here is a post on how to choose an optimal  binwidth : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114490/optimal-bin-width-for-two-dimensional-histogram